# Using React Router v6 to swap two different sections of my web app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using React Router v6 for my new web app.  I am using the Outlet with nested routes to swap out the `<main>` component and that is working nicely.  Now I also have an aside left panel to the left of the main component.  Within that side panel, there is a top section of buttons that I would like to swap as well based on the route.  How can I properly do that?  I know that you cannot have more than one Outlet.

Here is my main layout:

```
return (
    <div className={'d-flex flex-column h-100'}>
        <header className={'border-bottom'}>
            <h4>Title</h4>
        </header>
        <div className={'d-flex align-items-stretch h-100'}>
            <LeftPane /> <!-- second part to be swapped would be in this component -->
            <main className={'p-2'}>
                <Outlet />
            </main>
        </div>
        <footer className={'py-2 border-top'}>
            <div className={'d-flex flex-row w-50 mx-auto justify-content-between'}>
                <div>&copy; {year}</div>
                <div>company</div>
                <div>address</div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
);
```

And my router code is very simple:

```
<Router>
    <Routes>
        <Route path={'/'} element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path={'/dashboard'} element={<DashboardPage />}>
            <Route path={'ingredients'} element={<Ingredients />} />
            <Route path={'users'} element={<Users />} />
        </Route>
    </Routes>
</Router>
```

I am swapping different elements into the `main` section based on the route selected.  For instance when `Ingredients` is clicked, it will swap in the `Ingredients` section into the `<main>` section using the `Outlet`.

My `Ingredients` component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const Ingredients = () => {
    return (
        <div className={'d-flex'}>
            <h5 className={'title flex-grow-1 border-bottom text-start pb-1'}>
                Active Ingredients
            </h5>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Ingredients;
```

And here is a screenshot to show what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could continue the pattern of abstracting "common UI" into layout route components.

MainLayout

```
const MainLayout = () => (
  <div className={'d-flex flex-column h-100'}>
    <header className={'border-bottom'}>
      <h4>Title</h4>
    </header>
    <div className={'d-flex align-items-stretch h-100'}>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
    <footer className={'py-2 border-top'}>
      <div className={'d-flex flex-row w-50 mx-auto justify-content-between'}>
        <div>&copy; {year}</div>
        <div>company</div>
        <div>address</div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
);
```

LeftPaneLayout

```
const LeftPaneLayout = ({ leftPane = <LeftPane /> }) => (
  <>
    {leftPane}
    <main className={'p-2'}>
      <Outlet />
    </main>
  </>
);
```

Render the routes into the appropriate layout routes. Example:

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<MainLayout />}>
      <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" element={<DashboardPage />}>
        {/* Defaults to LeftPane component */}
        <Route element={<LeftPaneLayout />}>
          <Route path="ingredients" element={<Ingredients />} />
        </Route>

        {/* Use another leftPane component */}
        <Route element={<LeftPaneLayout leftPane={<SomeOtherPane />} />}>
          <Route path="users" element={<Users />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Comment: That was incredibly hard for me to wrap my head around.  But once I tinkered with it some, I got a better grasp of how it all worked.  Thank you so much!